# Atmosphere: Multiple subscriptions over single HttpConnection

Tags: java, atmosphere

I'm using Atmosphere in my Spring MVC app to facilitate push, using a `streaming` transport.

Throughout the lifecycle of my app, the client will subscribe and unsubscribe for many different topics.

Atmosphere seems to use a single http connection per subscription - ie., every call to `$.atmosphere.subscribe(request)` creates a new connection.  This quickly exhausts the number of connections allowed from the browser to the atmosphere server.

Instead of creating a new resource each time, I'd like to be able to add and remove the `AtmosphereResource` to broadcasters after it's initial creation.

However, as the `AtmosphereResource` is a one-to-one representation of the inbound request,  each time the client sends a request to the server, it arrives on a new `AtomsphereResource`, meaning I have no way to reference the original resource, and append it to the topic's `Broadcaster`.

I've tried using both `$.atmosphere.subscribe(request)` and calling `atmosphereResource.push(request)` on the resource returned from the original `subscribe()` call.  However, this made no difference.

What is the correct way to approach this?

Comment: I have exactly the same question: client subscribes to many broadcasters over one connection, with client adding and removing broadcasters at will. I didn't get as far as you in my tests though. Did you get any further with this? Surely it should be possible? Did you try the mailing list?

Comment: @Fletch Yep, got it going, thanks to some pointers from the guys on the IRC channel.  Posted my solution below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I got it working:

First, when the client does their initial connect, ensure that the atmosphere-specific headers are accepted by the browser before calling `suspend()`:

```
@RequestMapping("/subscribe")
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> connect(AtmosphereResource resource)
{
    resource.getResponse().setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", ATMOSPHERE_TRACKING_ID + "," + X_CACHE_DATE);
    resource.suspend();
}
```

Then, when the client sends additional subscribe requests, although they come in on a different `resource`, they contain the `ATMOPSHERE_TRACKING_ID` of the original resource.  This allows you to look it up via the `resourceFactory`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/subscribe", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> addSubscription(AtmosphereResource resource, @RequestParam("topic") String topic)
{
    String atmosphereId = resource.getResponse().getHeader(ATMOSPHERE_TRACKING_ID);
    if (atmosphereId == null || atmosphereId.isEmpty())
    {
        log.error("Cannot add subscription, as the atmosphere tracking ID was not found");
        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    AtmosphereResource originalResource = resourceFactory.find(atmosphereId);
    if (originalResource == null)
    {
        log.error("The provided Atmosphere tracking ID is not associated to a known resource");
        return new ResponseEntity<HttpStatus>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    Broadcaster broadcaster = broadcasterFactory.lookup(topic, true);
    broadcaster.addAtmosphereResource(originalResource);
    log.info("Added subscription to {} for atmosphere resource {}",topic, atmosphereId);

    return getOkResponse();
}
```

Comment: 'resource.getResponse().getHeader(ATMOSPHERE_TRACKING_ID)' doesn't seem to work for me (could be my fault). I have to call 'atmosphereResource.uuid()' instead.

Comment: How did you get an instance of the `broadcasterFactory` variable?